# Is it possible to turn off "Show Words" suggestion from plugin extension Code? Or if it is possible to turn it off for specific files?

Tags: typescript, intellisense, autosuggest

I want to disable the 'Show Words' ([abc]) suggestion in our plugin extension code. Similarly, I want to disable it for specific files that also originate from the plugin extension code.

I know how to turn off the "Show Words" suggestion in the local VSCode environment, but I want to achieve this through the plugin code.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) I'm not super familiar with the area you're describing, adding a photo of the thing you're referring to might add a bit of clarity to your question :)